# Hive: Regex for backslash

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to query for all rows that have a backslash character in between. This is the query I wrote:

select *  from table where A = '2014-10-30' and B rlike '.asterisk\.asterisk'

(Had to manually type asterisk. The query had the symbol itself)

It is returning the entire table whether or not column B has backslash.

'.*\\.*' returned no rows even though there are rows where B has a backslash character.

**Sample B** -  Hi can check the details for you/

Comment: Your example does not have a backslash in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_replace(datecolumn,'-','\\') as dt from tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

This question well explained in this blogpost.

https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/slashception-with-regexp_extract-in-hive/.

In short, the answer is:

Use 4 backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic guide on writing regular expressions: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_04.html

If you need to check whether backslash is in the string, try "instr" function, it is much simpler tran regexp: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions

As of regexp, it should be simply this: '\\'

One more good resource for checking regexp validity online: http://regex101.com/